# Why linux omits driver close function

Tags: multithreading, linux-device-driver

all.
I have my module - character driver for several DMA channels. It has open/close/ioctl functions for a user for each DMA.
Everything worked fine when used from one application thread - 3 DMAs worked as required.
When I added another thread to utilze one of DMAs separately I fall into very strange case - application call to function close() is executed with return code zero WITHOUT(!) entering my driver's close function (printk text is absent). Just to test, I called close() again immediately - it returned with errno=9 (bad descriptor). Closing the next channel in the next code line works fine.
I inserted all possible semaphores to protect the code both in the application and in the driver - no success.
I clearly understand that the issue is in some racing condition - delaying a bit the second thread solves the problem. But I can't catch it.
What, makes me crazy is - how can it be that function call close() does not reach my driver? I traced the call till the assembler "svc 0" - the file handler is correct, the return code is 0.
So, in which condition Linux may omit calling the driver function close()?

UPDATE: I inserted a call to the IOCTL function immediately after "not working" close() - the return code was -9 - bad file descriptor. This means that Linux really closed  this handler without entering my "close" function!

UPDATE2: I added a new IOCTL to the driver, which only calls the close() driver function directly. In the application: I called this new IOCTL just one line before calling close(). Everything now works fine!
More than that - I removed all semaphores for testing (I wrote everything reentrant, but added semaphores supposing an error)! Still everything is fine!

Comment: I think this question might be a little bit too generic to answer without looking at a [mre].

Comment: Marco, you are 100% right. But I do not imagine how to make such a minimal reproducible example without loosing my bug (I know this is my fault). Therefore I asked a specific question: is there something "regular" which can make Linux to return from "SVC 0" with return code zero without calling my driver function ( supposing that handle is ok). May be knowing this will help me to find my problem...

Comment: When the last link to the opened file is dropped, the `close` function of the driver is called with guarantee. Note, that the file descriptor is NOT the only source of the reference to the file. E.g. it could be several file descriptors for the same file, obtained via `dup`.

Comment: `dup` and `mmap` both add a reference to the open file description. `fork` will double the references to the open file description.

Comment: Also note that the final call of the driver's `release` file operation (when the reference count of the open file description has gone down to 0) is done from a work queue, asynchronously to the system call. So the system call can return before the `release` handler has been called.

Comment: Correction for `fork`: It will double the references that the parent process had to the open file description (because those references will be duplicated for the child process), not the total number of references to the open file description.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - Thanks for the statement "with guarantee". This was important for me. But I have no ```dup``` used.

Comment: Does the `release` handler get called when the process(es) that have the file open is (are) killed?

Comment: @Ian Abbot - please, clarify - how may reference count go to zero before ```release``` is called? Or does kernel first decrease the counter on app ```close()``` and then considers to call ```release```? If so, this may describe my problem as immediately after  ```close()``` I call for ```open()``` in the app.
But if this is the case, why kernel does not call driver's ```release``` while I am in gdb after ```close()``` call?

Comment: @Ian Abbot  And also my next coming ```open()``` fails because there was no ```release```.  Can it be that ```open()``` comes before work queue is emptied?

Comment: What I mean is that if your process code failed to close some file handle referring to an open file description, or failed to munmap an mmap'ed region associated with a (possibly closed) open file description, then killing the process should release all such references belonging to the process, which should result in the `release` handler being called for the file object if it has not already been called.

Comment: Killing the process is therefore a sanity check to test if you really have closed all the file descriptors that you think you have. Exiting the process forces them to be closed.

Comment: @Ian Abbot - 1001 of thanks to you. I found the issue. Just publishing the answer. Again, you are great!!!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ian Abbot the problem is found.
My driver needs one large memory region for control and one huge region for each channel buffer. For this, after the first `open()` call I called `mmap()` for the control region All consecutive calls to `open()` mmapped() only their corresponding buffer.
This effectively lead to the reference counter of the first file handler to be set to 2. And when I tried to "normally" close it, my driver's `release` function was not called! And, as it wasn't called, it did not clean the driver state and blocked further reopening.

SUMMARY OF THE THINGS I MISSED/didn't know:

1. `mmap` system call increases the reference call of the file.
2. `mmap` system call is per file and not per driver.

Again, thousands of thanks to Ian Abbot!